# SonataAdminBundle Security roles

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to secure some admin in SonataAdminBundle

I add SonataUserBundle with fosUserBundle for login.
So I can add users, groups and roles

in security.yml

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_IT: ROLE_IT
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_IT]


access_control:
    - { path: ^/sonata/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/sonata/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/sonata/login-check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/sonata, role: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/sonata/api/monolog, role: [ROLE_IT] }
```

I have to be connected to access Sonata

But every user can access the route /sonata/api/monolog even if they don't have ROLE_IT

How can I securize an Admin
And how can I only display the link if the user can acces to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use acl as the security handler.

Resources: [SonataAdminBundle Security](http://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html)

Answer (score 4):

The Admin user must have all roles in active security token.

If you do not have all the roles in the current state, then you should activate memory security provider and specify your account with all roles and reauth.

Comment: I'm doing this kind of security control, This answer seems right and have more upvotes, but I couldn't understand the answer. I'm using Symfony 2.7.1