# How to use roles in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, roles, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I started to use [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html) in a **Symfony2.1** application. I developed all the `Admin` classes and now I wish to add roles to prevent *view*, *list* and *edit* actions to such user groups (e.g. *non-admin users*).

Notice that I don't use the *SonataUserBundle* (derived from *FOSUserBundle*) and I want to use the `sonata.admin.security.handler.role` security handler provided by the Sonata: ACL is too much powerful (and provides a lot of overhead) for my small project.

My own *UserBundle* provides User class and Group class (the last used to specify the role of each user). The role hierarchy is provided in my *security.yml* file, e.g.:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_POST_AUTHOR:            ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:                  [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_POST_AUTHOR]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:            [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]
```

Now, I configured the config.yml file by specifying the security handler

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
```

The [official docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) are more focused on how using ACL and SonataUserBundle, so I don't know how to link my roles from *security.yml* with the SonataAdminBundle.

PS: A similar question is: [SonataAdminBundle Security roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911188/sonataadminbundle-security-roles).

Answer (score 19):

Try to create roles with `ROLE_<service.name>_<RIGHT>` where

- `<service.name>` is UPPER-CASE-ed and DOT-REPLACED-BY-UNDERSCORE version of your sonata admin service names
- `<RIGHT>` is one of ([reference](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/security.html#configuration)):

  - `CREATE`
  - `DELETE`
  - `EDIT`
  - `LIST`
  - `VIEW`
  - `EXPORT`
  - `OPERATOR`
  - `MASTER`

### Example

The following is a snippet from my **security.yml**:

```
role_hierarchy:

    ROLE_MANAGER:
        - ROLE_USER
        - ROLE_SONATA_STUFF # have no effect on the UI
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN # with this role you have a nice navbar with search box
        # user
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_VIEW
        # product
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_EDIT
        # product category
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_VIEW

    ROLE_ADMIN:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN # with this role you have a nice navbar with search box
        # user
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_EDIT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_EXPORT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_OPERATOR
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_MASTER
        # product
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_EDIT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_EXPORT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_OPERATOR
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_MASTER
        # product category
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_EDIT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_EXPORT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_OPERATOR
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MASTER
        # purchase
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_EDIT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_EXPORT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_OPERATOR
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PURCHASE_MASTER
        # payment
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_EDIT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_EXPORT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_OPERATOR
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PAYMENT_MASTER
        # notification: email template
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EDIT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXPORT
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_OPERATOR
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MASTER

    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:
        - ROLE_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN }
```

The following is a snippet from my **@AdminBundle/Resources/config/service.yml** (only service names are relevant here):

```
sonata.admin.user:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "User", label: "User" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]

sonata.admin.product:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\ProductAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Store", label: "Product" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]

sonata.admin.product_category:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\ProductCategoryAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Store", label: "Category" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductCategory
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]

sonata.admin.purchase:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\PurchaseAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Store", label: "Purchase" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Purchase
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]

sonata.admin.payment:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\PaymentAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Payment", label: "Payment" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity\Payment
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]

sonata.admin.notification.email_template:
    class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\Notification\EmailTemplateAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Notification", label: "Email Template" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\NotificationBundle\Entity\EmailTemplate
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]
```

### Reference

1. [Role Based Security in Sonata Admin](http://www.phpassionate.com/2013/05/05/role-based-security-in-sonata-admin/)

Comment: Still can't understand how to define the user and his role, after I describe all the possibilities.. Any ideas? :)

Comment: I have an entity with user roles and I define them in an extra sonata_roles.yml